# I want to create dataframe if it already doesn't exists in the location how to do that

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I want to check if the dataframe created is stored in a location or not. If not I want to create a new df with the same name.

Example:

List of df fromm the location :
list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

to_check = [df4]

```
for i in list1:
    if to_check in list1:
        read the file_
    else:
        create new df
```

I want to read the if its there. And create one if it doesn't exists

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists

Comment: you can also try to read the file and catch exceptions

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
if os.path.exists(f'./{to_check}.csv'):
    pd.read_csv(f'./{to_check}.csv')
```